# issues when installing nodejs for suse

Tags: suse, node.js

I need to install `npm` in my suse distribution, so naturally I followed https://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=devel%3Alanguages%3Anodejs&package=nodejs and https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#opensuse-and-sle but I got the same error and I didn't find out a way to fix it.

**Details**

```
       $ rpm -qf /etc/SuSE-release /etc/issue
sles-release-11.4-1.109

$ sudo zypper ar http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/languages:/nodejs/SLE_11_SP4/ Node.js

$ sudo zypper refresh
$ sudo zypper clean
$ sudo zypper update

$ sudo zypper install nodejs
```

> Loading repository data... Reading installed packages... Resolving
>   package dependencies...
>
> Problem: nothing provides openssl1 needed by nodejs-6.9.1-130.1.x86_64
>   Solution 1: do not install nodejs-6.9.1-130.1.x86_64  Solution 2:
>   break nodejs-6.9.1-130.1.x86_64 by ignoring some of its dependencies
>
> Choose from above solutions by number or cancel [1/2/c] (c):

Comment: Looks like you need to manually install `openssl1`

Answer (score 0):

openssl for SLES11SP4 is version 0.98

you need add **SECURITY Module** for SLES11SP4 which provides openssl1

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo zypper ar http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/languages:/nodejs/SLE_12_SP3/devel:languages:nodejs.repo
sudo zypper refresh
sudo zypper in nodejs
```

Based on Your OS select the url:

http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/languages:/nodejs/